# AWS cloudwatch metric filter

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

0
I want to filter out the some metrics from the cloud watch logs that are published from EC2 instance and i have already metric filter but when i am filtering out the keyword "Err" with process name "pro_col_iww_yww_post300932059" it is giving correct result. But i want to filter keyword Err with 4 or 6 defined process name then how would i create that filter pattern.

What I need - : i want to search Err keyword with process names - pro_col_iww_yww_post300932059, pro_col_wqw_wtw_post300123222, pro_col_wsw_jww_post300121271, pro_col_fww_lww_post300481214.

Example of log event below. 20231106 153001.563|0|MEWE|Err|0|0>[]|tid:1285|pro_col_iww_yww_post300932059|DataTransferProperties|m_iComponentID=415034598 m_sRemoteSystemName=Resource.Collect.SFtpType153761345088823 m_iRemoteSystemID=415678669 transferType=0 AuditItem=AuditItem1:|Role1:|AuditItem2:|Role2:| FileNameDate=AuditDateGettingFrom:UNKOWN|FileMode:UNKOWN|StartPos:-1|EndPos:-1|Splitter:NO SPLITTER|Sequence:-1| MinStartTime=MinTimeGetMode:NOT PROVIDE|FileMode:UNKOWN|StartPos:-1|EndPos:-1|Splitter:NO SPLITTER|Sequence:-1|

Question - I want to filter keyword Err with process name as mentioned above(these are fixed name) from the log events which have Err.

I tried - Err pro_col_iww_yww_post300932059
and %\bErr\b.*\b(pro_col_iww_yww_post300932059|pro_col_wqw_wtw_post300123222|pro_col_wsw_jww_post300121271|pro_col_fww_lww_post300481214)\b%